# Does Kentico allow query strings with question mark?

Tags: asp.net, kentico, querystringparameter

I'm trying to migrate my ASPX site to Kentico, and as part of my task I'm migrating URLs. I need to preserve my URL structure, so I need to keep URLs which look like : "foo.com/bar.aspx?pageid=1".

I checked page's "URLs" property tried to use wildcards, some patterns like `/bar/{pageid}- /bar/{?pageid?}-`, etc but Kentico always replaces question marks.

Is there a way to achieve that via the admin interface?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything in order to use  "foo.com/bar.aspx?pageid=1" url.

Create a page under the root and call it bar, so you'll get a page @ foo.com/bar.aspx. Kentico and/or .net does not care what you add to a url after question mark, so foo.com/bar.aspx?pageid=1 will work as well as foo.com/bar.aspx?someparam=sdf, or foo.com/bar.aspx?id=1&p=3&t=3.

You may (or may not) implement some functionality based on query string (e.g. paging), so it will parse query string and act in appropriate way.

Comment: What should i do if there are lots of pages in original site with urls like 'span.aspx?pageid=xxx' (they are not different pages of one document) and i need to keep this structure?

Comment: You've answered you question: this is a single page that acts/shows different data/content based on specified query string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

By default Kentico UI does not handle adding URL aliases with URL parameters like you show.  There is [an article on the DevNet](https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/url-redirection) for a URL Redirection module which has code you can import into your site to allow you to perform these redirects within the Kentico UI.  I'd suggest using this approach.

Unfortunately, I can't share a code sample since it's an article but it also has a [link to download the code](https://devnet.kentico.com/getattachment/Articles/2015-10/URL-Redirection/URLRedirection82.zip) too.  This appears to only be coded for Kentico 8.2 right now but I'm guessing you could do some work to make it work for other versions if you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are few concepts that you are clubbing here. I will start with your line code here

`/bar/{pageid}` - `{pageid}` is a positional parameter in Kentico's language if you choose to use dynamic URLS based on patterns. SO if you have a code that relies on pageid parameter to fetch some data then Kentico will pass that value. E.g in case of `/bar/420`, it will pass pageid as 420 different web parts on your template

`/bar/{?pageid?}` - This will search for query string parameter "pageid" on the request URL and replace its value here. So if you passed `foo.com/bar.aspx?pageid=366`, the resulting URL will be `/bar/366`

The #1 is positional parameter and #2 is the way in which Kentico resolves query string macros.

I hope this clarifies.